# share location with share intent Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-location

I need to share location from my app using the share intent activity, I have gone through some examples and know how to implement share intent. However I am stuck at setType. I need my application to share location details as well the users location on a map.

By the way i copied a users code with a very similar question"no offence"

Any assistance would be really appreciated.

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent1.setType("text/plain"); 
intent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The status update text"); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Select prefered Service"));
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the code to fire an intent to the map with a location:

```
String uri = "geo:" + latitude + ","
                    +longitude + "?q=" + latitude
                    + "," + longitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(uri)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but its not what i wanted, your code opens up google maps. i dont want to start google maps i just need my app to be able to share my current location more like google maps share location

Comment: Just adding a note for anybody taking this example and running with it. If you customize the "q" param, make sure you build the Uri safely: `String uri = Uri.Builder().scheme("geo").appendPath(lat +","+ lng).appendQueryParameter("q", name).build();`

Comment: You need to use `Intent.createChooser` to open an selection dialog with all apps that support that intent. See other answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
Double latitude = user_loc.getLatitude();
Double longitude = user_loc.getLongitude();

String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +latitude+","+longitude;

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
String ShareSub = "Here is my location";
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ShareSub);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Answer (score 1):

**for Kotlin Users**

```
val uri = "https://www.google.com/maps/?q=$latitude,$longitude"
        val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        sharingIntent.type = "text/plain"
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, uri)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share in..."))
```