# Display geopoint in Waze on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, geolocation, waze

I am trying to use Waze to show a point on the map.

This the intent:

```
String link = geo:?ll=32.26944,34.890442&z=10;
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link))
```

Instead of showing the point it puts me in navigation mode.
Weird thing is that if I use Google Maps instead then it works ok.

Is this a problem with Waze or my code?

Answer (score 5):

As you can see [here](https://www.waze.com/about/dev), they made it simpler:

**The following are the available parameters:**

```
search for address:         waze://?q=<address search term>
center map to lat / lon:    waze://?ll=<lat>,<lon>
set zoom (minimum is 6):    waze://?z=<zoom>
```

**Examples:**

```
center map to Ayalon and set zoom to 10     waze://?ll=37.44469,-122.15971&z=10
search for address:                         waze://?q=San%20Jose%20California
```

**And the Android API directly:**

> The following code snippet example will launch Waze to look for the
>   specified location, if Waze is installed. If Waze is not installed it
>   will open Waze page on the Market application.

```
try
{
   String url = "waze://?q=Hawaii";
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( url ) );
   startActivity( intent );
}
catch ( ActivityNotFoundException ex  )
{
  Intent intent =
    new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "market://details?id=com.waze" ) );
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What if I don't know place name but coordinates only. How would the url be?

Answer (score 1):

```
String uri = "geo:" + latitude + ","
                    +longitude + "?q=" + latitude
                    + "," + longitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(uri)));
```

This answer has the advantage of calling all apps that handle this functionality. In phone it shows Google Maps, Google Earth and Waze.

Recomendation: Use [ShareActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)! It displays the list of all possible apps that handle Geolocation.

Source:[This StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668551/share-location-with-share-intent-activity)

Answer (score 0):

try to input 32.26944 34.890442 ONLY. Do not use comma in between coordinates