# Sharing location via intent

Tags: android

I'm developing an app where I have to share a location from my activity to social media, until now I can share the location as link, but i want to share the location and display it as Whatsapp shows the location , i mean with the map image.

Can any one guide me to how to do this.
I'v tried the bellow

```
String geoUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + driveToLocation.getPosition().latitude + "," +
                    driveToLocation.getPosition().longitude ;

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Location Name");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, geoUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842144/sharing-map-based-location?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: this question has been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668551/share-location-with-share-intent-activity?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [share location with share intent Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668551/share-location-with-share-intent-activity)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use Google static map api. You may use an ImageView to show static maps image through url.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.400470,-122.072981&zoom=13&size=500x300&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE
```

To show image you just need lat and long.Just try it.
Share the above on Social Media.

OR

You may refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725916/convert-frame-layout-into-image-and-save-it) and convert layout into image and share it on social media.

Comment: Thank you it works , but the pin is not shown , and if i shared the image after downloading it form the url , will it opens if the user clicked it ?

Comment: how do you want to show it an image or other?

Comment: ok when you click on it it won't open image.